# Emacs 25 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, emacs, editor

Is there any way of installing Emacs 25 or 25.1 on Ubuntu 16.10 without having to compile from source?

I want a stable install of Emacs and do not wish to install an unstable or nightly build.

Comment: In particular, look at http://askubuntu.com/a/694228/15003.

Comment: @edwinksl Except that that question provides no useful or relevant answers or solutions to my problem.

Comment: @edwinksl I want a stable release of emacs, not a nightly build. Emacs 25 has been released for a while. Surprising, since it is one of the most popular editors out there.

Comment: Fair enough, though you might want to specify you don't want a nightly build just in case people offer `ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa` as an answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to the r/emacs post in Reddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/55hnxo/best_way_to_update_on_ubuntu/d8b8jtg/, the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs provides the stable release of Emacs 25. To add this PPA, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs25
```

Comment: This fixed async/await Python 3 file editing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worth upgrading even if *all* it added was this....

Comment: @Natim Hah! I was just hunting around for a fix to that issue!

Comment: also don't forget to remove emacs24: `sudo apt-get remove emacs emacs24*` (it's replaced by the `emacs25` package)